# Read output of running command continuously in present opened file

Tags: vim

I want to read the output of currently executing command in the opened buffer along with the echo message "running LINT". It will be helpful for large designs because the progress of the command is continuously visible in the presently opened file.

How do I simultaneously execute and echo the progress of the running command in `.vimrc` file .

I have written like:

`echo 'Running Lint '`

then defined my command `cmd`
finally used `execute '$read !'.cmd`

But I want to execute these two commands simultaneously. Pipe is not working here.

Comment: use **auto-refresh**